# Initial value problem with a two-variable function

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

I'm having a hard time with the following exercise from Numerical Methods:

> Let $f(t,x)=2tx, x(1)=1$ be initial value problem. Compute the expression of $x(t)$ and the exact value of $x(1.5)$.

We don't have a function of $x$, do we? Then, how am I supposed to calculate of the $x(1.5)$ with just that information?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, so f(t,x) is the separable equation? There're no differential signs with it. @Moo

Comment: You textbook almost certainly implies $x'(t) = f(t,x(t))$.

Comment: @CarlChristian How do you know $x′(t)=f(t,x(t))$?

Comment: I do not know, I *suspect* which is something entirely different. Your problem statement does not define an initial value problem. I suspect that some text is missing. The choice of $x'(t) = f(t,x(t))$ would correspond to the standard notation.